# Split string and assign parts from string to column name and row value

Tags: r

I have a string such as this:

```
PassengerData<-"prev_001_maskPc_12_routeFile_urban_suburban_half_capacity_seatsNotExcluded_ff_0865_PcCleanOnBandA_40_totalPax_43_seed_5625.csv"
```

I would like to split it as follows:

```
> d<-data.frame(prev=001,maskPc=12, routeFile="urban_suburban_half_capacity",seatsNotExcluded="seatsNotExcluded",ff=0865, PcCleanBandA=40,totalPax=43)
> d
  prev maskPc                    routeFile seatsNotExcluded  ff PcCleanBandA totalPax
1    1     12 urban_suburban_half_capacity seatsNotExcluded 865           40       43
```

So far I have

```
  PassengerData[1,1] %>% 
separate(file_name, into=c(NA,"file_name"), sep="Output_Passengers-",remove = TRUE)%>%
mutate(file_name=file_path_sans_ext(file_name)) %>% 
mutate(file_name=gsub(x = file_name,pattern  = "_",ignore.case = TRUE,replacement = " ")) %>% 
mutate(prev=str_match(file_name,"prev\\s*(.*?)\\s*maskPc")[,2]) %>% 
mutate(maskProp=str_match(file_name,"maskPc\\s*(.*?)\\s*routeFile")[,2]) %>% 
mutate(routeFile=str_match(file_name,"routeFile\\s*(.*?)\\s*seats")[,2]) %>% 
mutate(seats=str_match(file_name,"capacity\\s*(.*?)\\s*ff")[,2]) %>% 
mutate(flesh_flow=str_match(file_name,"ff\\s*(.*?)\\s*PcCleanOnBandA")[,2]) %>%
mutate(PcClean=str_match(file_name,"PcCleanOnBandA\\s*(.*?)\\s*totalPax")[,2]) %>% 
mutate(totalPax=str_match(file_name,"totalPax\\s*(.*?)\\s*seed")[,2],.keep="unused")
```

works for this case (I'm not sure how general it is) but what is there a way of splitting strings by strings between camelCase words for example? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

However between routeFile and seats* there could be 6 different variants:

```
1) routeFile_urban_full_capacity_seatsNotExcluded
2) routeFile_rural_full_capacity_seatsNotExcluded
3) routeFile_urban_half_capacity_seatsNotExcluded
4) routeFile_urban_half_capacity_seatsExcluded
5) routeFile_rural_half_capacity_seatsNotExcluded
6) routeFile_rural_half_capacity_seatsExcluded
```

Comment: Whats the pattern here? Are the column names always fixed and always presented in the string? Maybe give a couple of more examples

Comment: Thanks Sotos. It looks like urban_suburban_half_capacity could sometimes be rural_full_capacity. Other than that the follow a similar pattern.

Comment: So usually you have `column_name_value` ? What about `seatsNotExcluded`  ? It does not have a value. Will it always be the case? Are there other columns who will not have a value? For such cases do you want to replace column value with column name always? Yes adding couple of more rows would help to provide you a general solution.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah Thank you. I've added a working example of how it can be split in this case. I am told that there are 6 different combinations of the strings between routeFile and seats*. I will include them in the question.